# HorizontalScrollView Animation questions

Tags: android, animation, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView that I want to
use Animation to slide it up from the bottom of the screen
to it's height, and later slide it back down.
I want to be compatible with 1.6.

My main XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hscrollview"
    android:background="#45252525"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/hsvgallery"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" />

</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have two questions related to this.
One is, what should I use for the TranslateAnimation() Y,
to slide it up and later back down?  I'm currently trying to use one of these for
my slideUp().

```
TranslateAnimation tAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
    0.0f,
    0.0f,
    0.0f,
    iViewHeight);
```

or

```
TranslateAnimation tAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
    0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
    0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
    0.0f,
    Animation.ABSOLUTE,
    iViewHeight);
```

Where 'iViewHeight' is the height of the View with my
image and text, about 113 pixels.  I know it's a "Y delta", but it's confusing.

My other question is, Somebody said that this way to adjust the
new "top", isn't the best way to do it, and again what value
should I be using exactly?  Is there a better way to set the "top"?

```
tAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
{
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =
            (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)hScrollView.getLayoutParams();

        params.topMargin = iHeight;
        hScrollView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

}
```

At the moment the ListView takes up the whole screen
and my HorizontalScrollView isn't even showing up after I set things up
and try to start the Animation.

Thanks!

Comment: I am setting: setDuration(lDuration);  setFillEnabled(true);  and setFillAfter(false);

Comment: I finally got it to show up.   I found out that you can't do it using a LinearLayout.  I tried using a RelativeLayout and it appeared, but the Animation was messed up.  I'm still not sure about what to use for the settings, but I think I'll figure it out.. eventually.